# Why can't I do [UITextView "setText"] from with in a NSThread?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Crashes with "crashes here with EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when trying to setText within the thread.

???

thx

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>
{
    UITextView *tvCommand;
}
@end

---------

-(void) Thread_Tcp
{
    [tvCommand setText:@"HELLO"];//crashes here with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSThread *hThread = [NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(Thread_Tcp) object:nil];

    [hThread start];
}
```

Comment: `Thread_Tcp` is a poor choice of name for an Objective-C method. It's best to follow convention, and in this case, method names take the form of `lowerCamelCase` (with the small exception for methods that start with well-known acronyms, e.g. NSString's `UTF8String`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes to the UI should be done from the UI thread only. This concept is similar in most of the UI programming environments / frameworks.

You can fix it by calling:

```
-(void) Thread_Tcp
{
    [tvCommand performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"HELLO" waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

Comment: Do I put this code line in the Thread_Tcp?  I need to update tvCommand from within the Thread_Tcp somehow.  thx

Answer (score 3):

UIKit is not thread safe! Updating UI elements from a background thread may clobber the library's internal state and cause a crash. If you need to interact with any UI elements, do it in the main thread.

Use this to update the textView in the main Thread:

```
[tvCommand performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:@"HELLO" waitUntilDone:NO];
```